# Errors in the metadata manager when deploy cube

Tags: ssas

When I deploy cube, I got the following Error ?

Errors in the metadata manager. The measure group with the name of A already exists in the  cube.

Any Ideas ?

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to create two measure groups with the same name.

Comment: @TabAlleman thank you for your help. i have fixed this problems by restarting SSAS Server. and then it works.I do not know why